# How to get value based on a list of strings? If not in list then get Value Error

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, list, dataframe

I have some data and would like to know how I can get the values based on a list of strings below.

My data is people with a lot of money based on years as an index and I would like a value error to be raised if that name is not in that data frame.

```
 index      Bob       Andy       
 2000      50000     30000       
 2001      200000    400000      
 2003      250000    340000      
 ....      ....      .......
```

There are only two people's Money total data in this data frame. I would like a ValueError being raised if a person's name gets inserted like Ben ( ben is not in df) but if Bob gets inserted his money total will show up as an array with years.

My function atm:

```
def get_money_total(name = 'Bob'):

   list = ['Bob','Andy']

   if get_money_total == list:
          return np.array(df[['index',name]])
   
   else: 
       raise ValueError
```

With this function above when I give input:

```
get_money_total('Andy')
```

it just gives me a Valuerror but andy is in the data frame and in the list so why it not giving me the array with values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here first a reproducible example that creates the dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd

df = {'Bob': [1000, 3000], 'Andy': [2000, 2100]}

# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
```

The function that you need would look like this

```
def get_money_total(df, name = 'Bob'): 

   if name in list(df.columns):
          return df[name]
   else: 
       raise ValueError
```

As an argument you have the dataframe and the name you wanna check. Be aware that if you write name = 'Bob' the default name argument is Bob.

Output looks like this

```
# with default name = 'Bob'
get_money_total(df=df) 

Out[9]: 
0    1000
1    3000
Name: Bob, dtype: int64
```

Output for a name that isn't the column name of your dataframe

```
get_money_total(df=df, name = 'Ben')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-14-72369a2c95ba>", line 1, in <module>
    get_money_total(df=df, name = 'Ben')

  File "<ipython-input-12-f6cbe827aeeb>", line 7, in get_money_total
    raise ValueError

ValueError
```

Comment: And you shouldn't use the name list for a list like `list = ['Bob','Andy']` instead use something like  `mylist = ['Bob', 'Andy']` cause the keyword list is already used to change an element to a list element like I did here `list(df.columns)`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are comparing a funtion-type to a list, which is always be false.
What you want is to check, if the name exists in the indexs list.

Comment: Add an example and point out where the issue is to the original poster; they may not know how to check if name exists in the index list or what a function type is.